# ID of this flower/plant and origin if possible

Tags: species-identification, flowers

Hello again all you helpers out there!

So this plant or flower is found in Virginia (USA) rural area mainly woodland and grassplains, when it comes up, it rarely last for very long, so with a photo of the plant in its glory, i hope some of you could tell me, what kind of plant/flower it is and where it came from, thank you very much and have a great weekend!

/Beo

[image]

Comment: I assume you mean Virginia, USA, so I've edited that. Feel free to change if you mean Vancouver or whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look like a Spider lily (*Lycoris radiata*):

[image]

Source: [NC State University](https://plants.ces.ncsu.edu/plants/all/lycoris-radiata/)

Comment: Yea it does look like that one, thank you for your answer, ill try and read up on this one.